# How to restrict the typescript T to be only camplex object

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have this class definition

```
class abstract MyClass<T> { }
```

Which can be used as

```
class MyOtherClass extends MyClass<IInterface> { }
```

However I want to restrict to usage of this class with all simple types:

```
class MyOtherClass extends MyClass<string> { } //<-- do not allow
```

or

```
class MyOtherClass extends MyClass<nubmer> { }  //<-- do not allow
```

Basically I want to allow only T to be a complex object.

Any ideas how I achieve do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extends generic type from object

```
abstract class MyClass<T extends object> { }
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgsgTwMKvQB4AVBAUwA8IyA7AEwwHsQArM+APgQG8EBfAFACI2AA5kEASUk1qUAGZwJAXh4CEGpIwC2o5JQBcCEI0b7gNANwDBAlGgw4A8hAAWZKPgcBGclVoMWHgEYITSsh6KsGRcvIL26EEu7p4hAEx+1PSOwQ6EkFAAljQA5rH8diFJbh5e6ADMmQE5daE0AK7aIB7lfEA)

Comment: oh i see, is it the best way of doing it? is there any other approach?

Comment: as I know this is the easiest and most working way, maybe other users will suggest a better way

Comment: You may wish to link to the relevant documentation: [generic constraints](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#generic-constraints)

Comment: any ideas on that https://stackoverflow.com/q/63132286/2926340 ?