# How to restrict the typescript T to be only primitive object

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Yesterday I ask this question [How to restrict the typescript T to be only camplex object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63117325/2926340)
Now I wonder how to actually do the opposite?

```
class abstract MyClass<T> { }
```

I want only allow primitive types (string, boolean, etc) like:

```
class MyOtherClass extends MyClass<string> { } //<-- allowed

class MyOtherClass extends MyClass<IInterface> { } //<-- not allowed
```

What is the best way to achieve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create custom primitive type, which would you like to allow

```
type IPrimitiveTypes = string | number | boolean;

abstract class MyClass<T extends IPrimitiveTypes> { }
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=54&pln=1&pc=1#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgsgTwMKvQB4AVBAUwA8IyA7AEwwEkAFKASwFs2I2A3M4tgAOZMAD4EAbwQBfAFByIwsgkaMa1KADM4KgLxS5CY0gD2HIckoAuBCFOmrwGgG458pSNWtO3PgOUMA0h2GgBzBAAfBBoAVw4QMigouwcnVwUUNAwcAHkIAAsk-GyARnIqWgYsPAIwQjUNJJ1YMglpeSz0GvyiqBL0ACYK6noc2uzCELZw9tk5LvHe4rqAZhGq8YH6uISkuZkgA)

Comment: is it the only way?

Comment: This is the way.

Comment: Again the same answer, I don't know of another option, but maybe someone will suggest something else :)

Answer (score 3):

```
type Primitive =
  | boolean
  | number
  | bigint
  | string
  | symbol
  | null
  | undefined;

abstract class MyClass<T extends Primitive> { }
```