How to derive the type on a generic class that is constrained to primitives in TypeScript?
I want to constrain my generic Foo class to accept only certain types.
Also, I need to auto-derive the type by the default value that is passed to the constructor of Foo.
With just Foo<T>, when I call new Foo("bar") the type is Foo<string>. That is what I want.
However, when I try to restrict type T as seen below, when I call new Foo("bar") the type is Foo<"bar">. Is there a way to make the compiler to still derive string?
Works nice:
  class Foo<T> {
    constructor(private value: T) { }
  }
  
  const foo = new Foo("bar"); // this derives type Foo<string> for foo

My Problem:
  type FieldTypes = string | number | boolean | Date | null;

  class Foo<T extends FieldTypes> {
    constructor(private value: T) { }
  }
  
  const foo = new Foo("bar"); // this is of type Foo<"bar">. Why?

This should also be derived to Foo<string>, without explicitly defining
const foo:Foo<string> = new Foo("bar"); .
Is there a better way to constraint my Foo Types?

You can use a Foo<"bar"> anywhere that would accept a Foo<string> (https://tsplay.dev/mZdBEw), what problem is the narrower inference causing? Note also you can explicitly new Foo<string>("bar") if necessary.

Constraints narrow intentionally, as described in ms/TS#10676. If you want to avoid that you'll have to change/remove the constraint. Maybe instead of T extends FieldTypes you can write value: T & FieldTypes? This might have other weird downstream effects but it will prevent narrowing in your example code as shown in this playground link. Otherwise you'll need to refactor to some other more annoying form. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

@jcalz It seems like the perfect answer to me. Thank you!
Intersection with "&" instead of "extends" looks like the way to go here? The Answers I found so far all suggested "extends". Is there a reason for this?
https://stackoverflow.com/a/63132371/372459
What are the "weird downstream effects" you are talking about?
Also, thank you for the enlightening TS-Link.

oh, dang! I found the problem (the type of "loo" is string & Fieldtypes and not string): TS-Playground

That narrowing is intentional, as per microsoft/TypeScript#10676. By constraining T to a type including string, TypeScript takes that as a hint that you probably want string literal types. That is often exactly what people want, but in your case it's not.
There are lots of possible workarounds here, but the easiest one is to not constrain T at all directly, but just force usages of T to be assignable to FieldTypes, such as by using an intersection:
class Foo<T> {
    constructor(private value: T & FieldTypes) { }
}

const foo = new Foo("bar"); 
// const foo: Foo<string>

This might meet your needs, or it might give you trouble later. But it's easy.

More complicated is to just take over the way the constructor signature works, by writing an explicit literal-widening utility type
type Widen<T> = 
  T extends string ? string : 
  T extends number ? number : 
  T extends boolean ? boolean : 
  T;

and renaming Foo out of the way
class _Foo<T extends FieldTypes> {
    constructor(private value: T) { }
}

and redefining Foo to be a type and a constructor value, where the constructor explicitly returns a widened version of the type argument:
type Foo<T extends FieldTypes> = _Foo<T>;
const Foo = _Foo as new <T extends FieldTypes>(value: T) => Foo<Widen<T>>;

It behaves the same way:
const foo = new Foo("bar");
// const foo: Foo<string>

But it's cumbersome so without more detailed use cases, I'd go with the easy approach first.
Playground link to code

it won't as in type definition you are explicitly saying that the type is "foo".
You can do
const foo: Foo<string> = new Foo("bar"); // this WILL be of type Foo<string>


Sorry. The code was misleading. I changed the example. I hope my problem is clear now.
